# Question about a proof that there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand a proof that there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. Most of the steps are clear to me but I don't quite get the part where the author constructs an injection between $^{\mathbb{N}}2$ and $\mathbb{R}$, in particular the one marked in yellow.

[image]

Note that $^{\mathbb{N}}2$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set $2=\{0,1\}$, so it is the set of binary sequences.

I know that $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{3^{i+1}} = \frac{2}{3} \sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{i}} = \frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}} = 1$. Hence, $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{2a_i}{3^{i+1}}$ also converges absolutely since $\frac{2a_i}{3^{i+1}} \leq \frac{2}{3^{i+1}}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

But how does this help me with proving that $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{2a_i}{3^{i+1}} = \sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{2b_i}{3^{i+1}} \implies (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} = (b_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, i.e. $a_i = b_i$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: $f$'s definition can be restated as $f(S)=\sum_{i\in S}2/3^{i+1}$. Is $h[r]$ shorthand for $\{h(q)|q\in\Bbb Q\land q<r\}$?

Comment: Hint: obtain bounds on $3^{\inf S}f(S)$ for nonempty $S\subseteq\Bbb N$.

Comment: @J.G. $r$ is a Dedekind cut and $h[r]$ denotes the image of $r$ under $h$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $k$ is the smallest index with $a_k \ne  b_k$. We may assume wlog that $a_k = 1$ and $b_k = 0$. Then
$$\frac{a_k}{3^{k + 1}} + \sum \limits_{i = k + 1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{3^{i + 1}} = \sum \limits_{i = k + 1}^\infty \frac{b_i}{3^{i + 1}}.$$

Since the $a_i$ are all non-negative, this leads to the contradiction
$$1 = a_k \le 3^{k + 1}\sum \limits_{i = k + 1}^\infty \frac{b_i}{3^{i + 1}} \le 3^{k + 1} \sum \limits_{i = k + 1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{i + 1}} = \frac{1}{3} \sum \limits_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^i} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Nice proof, but I think there is a typo in the last equation. It should be $b_i$ instead of $b_k$, right?

Comment: @DerivativesGuy Indeed, i have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $\ a_i\in\{0,1\}\ $ for all $\ i\ $, then
$$
\left\lfloor3^{n+1}\sum_{i=n}^\infty\frac{2a_i}{3^{i+1}}\right\rfloor=2a_n\ .
$$

Comment: Ok, so then $2a_n = \sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{2a_i}{3^{i+1}} = \sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{2b_i}{3^{i+1}} = 2b_n$, correct? And this is true for all $n$, right?

Comment: Not quite: $\ 2a_0=\left\lfloor3\sum_\limits{i=0}^\infty\frac{2a_i}{3^{i+1}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor3\sum_\limits{i=0}^\infty\frac{2b_i}{3^{i+1}}\right\rfloor=2b_0\ $, and consequently $\ \sum_\limits{i=\color{red}{1}}^\infty\frac{2a_i}{3^{i+1}}=\sum_\limits{i=\color{red}{1}}^\infty\frac{2b_i}{3^{i+1}}\ $.  Now use induction and the identity in the hint to get the result.

Comment: I actually missed the brackets the first time I read your answer. Are the brackets used for the floor function? I think I'm not really following what you are trying to do. The proof by Dominik is fine for me though, so you don't need to elaborate if you don't want to/don't have time. Of course, feel free to turn your hint into an answer for other people.

Comment: Yes, the brackets represent the floor function.  Successive application of the formula in the hint for $\ n=0,1,2,\dots\ $ just successively peel off the ternary digits (namely, the $\ a_i$s) of the number $\ f((a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}})\ $.  Since you've got an answer that satisfies you, and mine was only intended as a hint anyway, I won't bother turning it into a full answer.

Comment: Brain fart: "the ternary digits (namely, the $\ a_i$s)".  The ternary digit in the $\ (i+1)^\text{th}\ $ place is $\ \color{red}{2}a_i\ $ rather than $\ a_i\ $ itself.